# Is there an element outside a ring that maps an ideal of the ring to a subset?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $I \subset R$ a finitely generated proper ideal, and $K$ a field containing $R$. Let $\alpha_i$ be an arbitrary set of generators of $I$, and define the column matrix $v = [\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]^\intercal$. My question is, does there exist $\gamma \in K - R$ such that the entries of $\gamma v$ sum to an element of $I$?

I tried to prove that there isn't such a $\gamma$ by the following argument. For every element $j \in I$ there is some diagonal matrix $M$ with entries in $R$ that maps $v$ to a column matrix representing $j$, e.g. if $j = a_1 \alpha_1 + \cdots + a_n \alpha_n$, then $Mv = [a_1\alpha_1, \dots, a_n \alpha_n]^\intercal$. So if $\gamma v = Mv$, then $\gamma$ must be an eigenvalue of $M$. Since $M$ is diagonal, $\gamma$ must be an entry in $M$, which implies $\gamma \in R$, a contradiction.

Can someone verify if this is true or if not, show which step in the proof is incorrect?

---

For context, I'm reading Number Fields by Daniel Marcus. There is a proof that if $I$ is an ideal of a Dedekind domain, there is an ideal $J$ such that $IJ$ is principal (Theorem 15). The proof uses a similar linear algebra trick to show that $\gamma$ is algebraic over the ring, and since the ring is a Dedekind domain $\gamma$ must be in the ring. I am trying to understand whether we have to assume $\gamma$ algebraic $\Longrightarrow$ $\gamma \in R$ or if such a $\gamma$ would still be in $R$ without this assumption.

Comment: Do we want some additional assumption on the set $\{\alpha_i:i\}$? Should it be a minimal set of generators?

Comment: You can get a vertically centred ellipsis with proper spacing to surrounding binary operators like $+$ using `\cdots`.

Comment: @user469053 Is the proof easier if we assume it's a minimal set? I don't see right away where it would affect things so would be great if you can clarify. If it makes it easier I don't mind adding that condition.

Comment: If you don't assume it's a minimal set, you can have two generators $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ with $\alpha_2=-\alpha_1$, in which case $\nu=0$ and $\gamma\nu\in I$ for all $\gamma$.

Comment: Oh yeah, makes sense. Really I want to consider $v$ as a non-zero vector with entries in $R$, so when we multiply by the scalar $\gamma$ we get $Mv$. Can I just specify that the generating set is minimal or should I reword in terms of vectors?

Comment: I don't really understand how you're switching between vectors and elements of $R$. In what sense is $v$ a vector and what does $Mv=j\in R$ mean?

Comment: @Ben I just rephrased the question, hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: As I understand it, my counterexample below also works for the updated question, doesn't it?

Comment: As written, it seems that there's a simple counterexample with $K = \mathbb{Q}, R = \mathbb{Z}, I = 2\mathbb{Z}$, and $\gamma = \frac{1}{2}$. Am I misreading something?

Comment: I think I messed things up when I revised the question. I should have said "the sum of entries of $\gamma v$ are in $I$." In the simple case you gave, $\gamma v = 1$ is not in $I$ but in Ben's answer $\gamma v = y^2 + x \in I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample to the original question: Consider $R=k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$ and the ideal $I=(x,y)$. Notice: $\frac{x}{y}(x+y)=y^2+x\in I$, whilst $\frac{x}{y}\in K-R$.